# How to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nx}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}dx$ using the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

How would one compute this integral using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiAw8.png

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem and where are you stuck? If you know what the dct says it should be easy to apply it here, though justifying that application (i.e. showing the premises of dct hold) might require some thought.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
$$-\frac 12 \leq \frac{u}{u^2+1} \leq \frac 12\\x>0 \to 0\leq \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}\leq \frac 12$$

Answer (score 0):

The following is not exactly, which you wish, but maybe it will help.

It's just $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+n^2)}{2n}=0.$$

Comment: The question asks to use dct. The fact that there is an "exact solution" is interesting but not an answer.

Comment: What do you want that I'll do?

Comment: Say at the top that you aren't using dct so you  don't leave op the impression that dct is being invoked here somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Let us find the maximum value of your integrand $f_n(x)$ on $x\in[0,1]$. Differentiating, we have

$$f_n'(x)=\frac{(1+n^2x^2)n-nx(2n^2x)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}=0 \implies (1+n^2x^2)n-nx(2n^2x)=0 $$

Expanding, we have

$$-n^3x^2+n=0\implies x^2=\frac{1}{n^2} \implies x = \frac{1}{n}$$

But $f_n(1/n)=1/2$. And $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(1)=\frac{n}{1+n^2}\leq\frac{n}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$. So $|f_n(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ on $x\in[0,1]$.